# Running Multiple Queries through Shell Script

Tags: mysql, shell

I have 6 MySQL Queries and I need to run queries via shell script and the result should get imported in CSV file I know how to run a single MYSQL query through shell script but how to run multiple queries throught Shell script.

Comment: This is essentially what you asked in your last question: [How should I write a Perl script to input MySQL queries and output in CSV format?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7253077)

Answer (score 1):

Just put a ";" between all your queries.

```
SELECT something FROM sometable; UPDATE …
```

Comment: Ok I did that and its wirking ,what i need id I have 6 select statements in MYSQL and if user wants to call first statement then he can call it by saying ./script.sh -s statement 1